# route with optional parameters in querystring

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario where search can be performed only either of one value (id or age or sex).

If i use below route where only id is passed,

```
this.router.navigate(['details'],
{
     queryParams: 
     {
         id: this.id,
         age: this.age,
         sex: this.sex,
     }
 })
```

url will look like http://path/details?id=10&age=&sex=

I want my url to be like

path/details?id=10 on id search

path/details?age=25 on age search

So i refactored my code to,

```
if(this.id) {
    this.router.navigate(['details'],
    {
         queryParams: 
         {
             id: this.id
         }
     })
}else if(this.age){
    this.router.navigate(['details'],
    {
         queryParams: 
         {
             age: this.age
         }
     })
}else if(this.sex){
    this.router.navigate(['details'],
    {
         queryParams: 
         {
             sex: this.sex
         }
     })
}
```

Is there better way to refactor the code to avoid if statement

Comment: IMHO, this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this, :

```
this.router.navigate(['details'],
{
     queryParams: 
     {
         id: this.id || null,
         age: !this.id && this.age || null,
         sex: !this.id && !this.age && this.sex || null
     }
 });
```

The above will give you the result.